# Load Window within iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a iframe on my page that has a link that opens a window to xyz.com.
The only thing is it automatically opens this window outside of the iframe. 
I've embedded this script inside the iframe page:

```
<script>
function open_win()
{
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes,        directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes,   width=400, height=400");
}
</script>
</head>
```

The window displays, but it displays outside of everything when I just want it to display inside the inframe.

Comment: you cannot open more than one window inside of an iframe.

Comment: Iframe [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/)

Answer (score 2):

Browser windows have web pages in them, which can contain iframes.

You cannot put a window inside an iframe. That'd be a window in an iframe in a web page in a window, which would just be bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

To keep that new content inside the iFrame, perhaps you should use a show/hide layer instead.

Comment: I was looking through some answers and I changed the target to parent, but now that just redirects to the popup window.